# Logic of number of Reducers

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, reduce

Suppose in a MR job , **the mappers gives out two unique keys only**. I am setting the **reducer count to 4**. Now my hashpartitioner will always send the two type of keys to two reducers , suppose R1 and R2.
I want to know what happens to R3 and R4. **Are they running? If not then why? 
Also how many part files will be formed ?**

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

They will run because they will start before it is known that they aren't going to receive any keys. Four part files will be created, but two of them will not contain any records.

Comment: Thanks Jeremy.. The two parts files will be of 0 bytes size?